# Better code/text editing for posts and pages?

Tags: plugins, posts, pages, tinymce, editor

What is the most well known or liked method or plugin to improve the text editor for posts/pages? I would love to have syntax highlighting and formatting, along with other IDE type functionality in the editor, although I can't find any plugins that do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen a lot of people using GIST or GIT where I assume they can embed their code into a post or page. Not a plugin but at least all your code snippets are in one place and if Wordpress ever breaks, your code is safe on GIT. I'm using crayon syntax highlighter if you're looking for a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/ The plugin doesn't replace the text editor tab in Tiny MCE, instead it allows you to wrap code within the visual tab. There's also this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Answer (score 0):

Hey If you want to improving your text editor for post and pages then use Gust Wordpress Plugin

[Gust](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gust/)

I think you like it.